# What the slots on the back of tower PC case are for?

Tags: case, connector

I'm wondering how these slot were supposed to be utilized, especially that 5.2mm (by the looks of it) DC input.

I know enough about PCI/PCI-e slots. The question is related to those specific unusual slots, I have never seen before. If possible, could you provide with some images of the hardware, which could be fit into those slots?

The case is Tracer tro-585.
[image: The back of tro-585 PC tower case]

Comment: Open the case and see what is on the other side on the motherboard

Comment: some motherboards don't have outputs for older optional ports like serial DB9, RS232, external SCSI, Parallel, etc, but they put a block of header pins on the board (or you buy a card), that you can connect a dongle to. Dongles might mount in an expansion card slot like this one: https://www.startech.com/Cables/Serial-Parallel-PS-2/DB9-DB25/1-Port-16in-DB9-Serial-Port-Bracket-to-10-Pin-Header-Low-Profile~PLATE9M16LP but if you don't have free expansion slot, you can just mount the external connector directly to the case in the slots you are indicating.

Comment: Those are slots for serial, parallel and other types of ports. The round hole is most likely for a wireless antenna mount.

Comment: @SirAdelaide, I'm not interested in ISA/PCI/PCI-e/etc slots on motherboard and relating cuttings on the back of the PC case. The question is only related to those slots on the photo provided

Comment: @SirAdelaide  You wrote "Open the case and see what is on the other side on the motherboard" <-- if you look at the pic you should be able to see that the slots are not aligned with the motherboard so no if he looks on the motherboard he won't get a good hint.

Comment: @FrankThomas any idea what the slot with the third and fourth from the left are, I see they have three notches one each end like three little feet!

Comment: What might help is the manual for the computer case.

Comment: @barlop, the problem is that I cannot find any manual for that case, and I never had it

Comment: Some older connectors had a "clamp"(?) to hold the connector in place instead of a screw. The "extension" could be there to hold it in place. An example would be old parallel ports. [Female side with "clamps"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Centronics-36F.jpg) and [male side with notches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mini-Centronics_36_pin_with_Micro-Centronics_36_pin.jpg).

Comment: @barlop, I believe that they are SCSI, and D-SUB 68 pin, which are wider ports, but thats just a guess. see here for images of hundreds of differant ports with their pinouts. http://connector.pinoutguide.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What the slots on the back of tower PC case are for?

They are not called "*slots*".
They are called "knockouts", because the inner piece of sheet metal is supposed to be knocked out (but more easily pried out) to create the opening.
The opening is typically referred to as a "cutout" (i.e. an opening cut out of the sheet metal).

The cutouts are for installation of additional connectors.  The two smallest knockouts (on the left) are definitely intended for DB9 and DB25 connectors.

The cutout (or just holes) labeled "DC -- 5V, 3A" is probably for a DC-power barrel connector similar to:
[image]

Comment: thank you for the clarifications. But the barrel connector does still not make sense, if all PC PSUs have 5V

Comment: @Qeeet -- This barrel connector would be for a power source.  The internal connection would be to the PC's 5 DCV supply (with a 3A fuse?).  The connector would allow powering of external equipment, such as a USB hub.  A female connector might be the proper gender for a power source, but the male is the only images of a panel-mount connector that I could find.